# Array -digit count

Tags: c

Let A=a1,a2,..an is an array of integers. The size of the array n and the elements of the array are read from SI. Write a program that will transform the array so each element of the original array is replaced with the number of appearance of the least significant digit (the right most) in the number itself. Print the result array on the standard output.

Compute the count of given digit in a number with separate recursive function.

Input: 
5
1   11   1121   111222112   22222

Output:
1 2 3 4 5

Comment: Please show the code that you have so far.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/, http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/, http://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion

Answer (score 0):

```
int i;
for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
    int right_most_digit=a[i]%10;
    a[i]/=10;
    int count=1; //count is equal to 1 as we have already taken the right most digit
    while(a[i]!=0){
        int digit=a[i]%10;
        if(digit==right_most_digit) count++;
        a[i]/=10;
    }
    a[i]=count;
}
```